# Creating classes dynamically in python

Tags: python, oop

Is it a good coding practice to have the class name as variable.
E.g

```
def create_class(class_name):
   class class_name:
     def __init__(self):
       do_sth....
   class_instance = class_name()
   return class_instance


for object in objects:
      res = create_class(object)
```

I wanted to create different classes which are present in a list like objects=[person,vehicle, location ..]. What could be other alternative way to do it ?

Comment: You should probably use dicts.

Comment: What do you mean by *the name of a class as variable*?

Comment: @Guy Just edited..The class name is variable.

Comment: You know you are not actually creating a dynamic class name here? regardless of what the content of the parameter is the class will still be `class_name`.

Comment: That's an utterly bad practice. Use dataclasses or dicts.

Comment: You have conflicting `class_name` usage. One is the argument to the function, and the other is the name of the class. You can't use the same name for both.

Comment: I have found the **types** library to be useful. 
`types.new_class(class_name, (BaseClass,), **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0):

**class_name** is a class, you can set a name property for your class, like this:

```
class class_name:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


objects=["person","vehicle","location"]
for obj in objects:
    res = class_name(obj)
    print(res)
```

Comment: Even with the `.name` attribute, it's still the _same class_. This just creates _different instances_ of it.

Comment: yeah i know, it will be always a **class_name** object , he needs to code a class for each objects , attributes/properties aren't the same ( i guess ... ?). Is there a reason to create a  dynamic class, if they have the same attributes why didn't make you inheritance?